# Write a function that results the sum of two integers using bitwise operations, w\o conditional operation

Tags: code-golf, math

- You cannot use `if`,`while`,`for`, `?:`, `||`, `&&` etc., or recursion!
- Assume it is Int.32
- Shortest answer wins

Comment: They use control flow with the `?:` operators.

Comment: (i) `?:` is not "control flow", it's just an operator and it may well be branchless; (ii) if you don't want to allow the ternary conditional operator then you should state this in the question.

Comment: @PaulR - Unless I am misunderstanding, `?:` equates to an **if-then** statement. If it is not considered a part of control-flow, then what is it considered? I was going based off of this [Control flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) wikipedia entry.

Comment: No - it doesn't equate to if-else (in C and related languages at least) - it's just an operator, which in some limited cases you can use to replace if-else, but it's still just an operator nonetheless, and its use does not necessarily imply branching. Anyway, I see you've changed the rules now to exclude `?:` so I guess that makes its use moot.

Comment: @PaulR hmm yes, it **does** imply branching. Code inside the `?:` operator is not executed unless the condition is met. And that is what a branching is.

Comment: @Dokkat: if you look at the code generated by any reasonably modern compiler you will see that in many simple cases that branchless instruction sequences are generated, so no, `?:` does not necessarily imply branching. Try it with e.g. `y = a > b ? a : b;`.

Comment: @PaulR if that is the point, so does if-then-else. Try `int x; if (a>b) x=a; else x=b;`.

Comment: The subtle difference though is that `?:` is an *operator*, which *evaluates* either of two *expressions*. OTOH if/else is a control flow construct. Anyway, the argument is now moot, as the rules have been changed.

Comment: Yea but I just want to make it clear for the reader that it is more of a definitions difference than an actual difference. The only actual difference between those, in general, is that you can fit the `?:` operator where C expects expressions, and you can have statements inside the `if-then-else`. The separation between statements and expressions itself is an error and can be considered historical baggage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### C - 91

Based on Kogge-Stone, there is probably ways to cut parts of this off, but it seems good enough to start the race.

```
g,p;t(h){g|=p&g<<h;p&=p<<h;}d(a,b){g=a&b,p=a^b;t(1);t(2);t(4);t(8);t(16);return a^b^g<<1;}
```

An ungolfed version and possibly some explanation can be found from http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Parallel+Prefix+Algorithms

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (66 chars)

```
def a(i,j):v=locals();exec("i,j=i^j,(i&j)<<1;"*32,v);return v['i']
```

Comment: Nice workaround for the loop limitation. I wonder if I could do something similar with macros.

Answer (score 0):

### J - <strike>8</strike>14

A better version

```
+&.(1&(32 b.))
```

Which does: sum under rotate bits which means (for people who don't speak J):
do rotate on both arguments, sum them, inverse the rotation.

This way the bit operation is really used in the result.

Comment: First of all: I have no idea what your code does. My comment is written as if you just summed two numbers in a completely normal manner.    I think "write -- sum -- using bitwise operations" does include both of the requirements. Usually I like cheaters in code-golf, but if we continue on this path the questions will have to be written in formal mathematical definitions. I don't want to go there.

Comment: @shiona to be fair, the title is not really a requirement. The OP should have put more in the body of the question.

Comment: you are right, the result of the bitop is not really used . Here's a better one...

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript, 3 (or 7, if it needs to be assigned to a function)

Since you never said `+` was forbidden

```
0|+
```

`0|` basically does nothing (if the top of the stack is a number), because `n [bitwise or] 0` is `n`.

`+` adds them.

If it needs to be a function:

```
{0|+}:s
```

Assigned to function `s`.